# Java Serialization - readbObject works, but operations on the read object do not work

Tags: java, serialization

So I've created a program that can create / store / and manipulate tests and surveys. I serialize the objects created, save, load and utilize them.

So far, everything with the serialization works, however when I try to load Test / Survey Objects, I can't, for instance, print the questions and possible answers associated with the Test / Survey.

Below is the code inside the FileLoader class which is responsible for saving and loading documents:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// Method : saveDocument
/// @Description - saves test to a file
/// @param[in] <test> - a test object to save
/// @return <void>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void saveDocument(AbstractQuestionContainer document)
{
    container = document;

    try
    {
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        objectOutput.writeObject(container);

        objectOutput.close();           
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Finding File: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Saving Test: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// Method : loadDocument
/// @Description - loads documentName into an object
/// @param[in] <documentName> - the name of the document to load
/// @return <void>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public AbstractQuestionContainer loadDocument() throws IOException
{
    container = new AbstractQuestionContainer();

    try
    {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(workingFile);
        ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

       container = (AbstractQuestionContainer) objectInput.readObject();

       objectInput.close();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(EOFException e)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    return container;
}
```

Again, the only functionality that I need to use with loaded objects is the ability to print out the questions associated with Test and their possible answers. When I make the printDocument call in the Driver class, nothing gets displayed. To me, this indicates that the object is loaded, but not loaded properly somehow.

I've scoured Stack relating to Object Serialization and have not found anything that helps in relation to this matter. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Here is how the code is called:

```
    if(buildBuffer.size() == 1)
    {
        AbstractQuestionContainer document = buildBuffer.get(0);
        loader.saveDocument(document);
        buildBuffer.remove(0);

        System.out.println(documentToSave + " has been saved.");
        System.out.println();
    }
    else
    {
        // loop over build buffer and find file
        for(int i = 0; i < buildBuffer.size(); i++)
        {   
            if(buildBuffer.get(i).fileName().equals(loader.getFileName()))
            {
                loader.saveDocument(buildBuffer.get(i));
buildBuffer.remove(i);                                                          
            }
        }

        System.out.println(documentToSave + " has been saved.");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

And the loading:

```
// if the size of the build buffer is 1, then there's only one thing to load, so load it.
if(buildBuffer.size() == 1)
{
    loadBuffer.add(buildBuffer.get(0));
    buildBuffer.remove(0);

    System.out.println("Document " + documentToLoad + " loaded to the buffer successfully");
    System.out.println();
    break;
}
else
{
    for(int i = 0; i < buildBuffer.size(); i++)
    {
        if(buildBuffer.get(i).fileName().equals(loader.getFileName()))
        {
            loadBuffer.add(buildBuffer.get(i));
            buildBuffer.remove(0);

            System.out.println("Document " + documentToLoad + " loaded to the buffer successfully");
            System.out.println();
            break;
        }
    }
}

// check to see if given file is in local directory
boolean exists = new File(filePath, documentToLoad).exists();

// if the file exists, load it, and add it to the loadBuffer
if(exists)
{
    container = loader.loadDocument();
    loadBuffer.add(container);

    System.out.println("Document " + documentToLoad + " loaded to the buffer successfully");
    System.out.println();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Error: File entered does not exist in either the buildBuffer or local directory.");
    System.out.println();
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Please help us reproduce by providing us with a full example of how do you call this code, what is the actual output vs. expected output and etc.

Comment: I've updated the post. I would include more code, but I don't want the post to get overcumbersome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `file`? What is all this stuff about loaders? Why are you constructing and returning a blank object in the case of an exception reading the object?

Comment: The loader calls that you see refer to the FileLoader class, which is where the loadDocument and saveDocument code is located. file refers to the file fed in.

Comment: So, it seems to me that you are using the built-in Java Serialization facility to provide a persistent file format for your project.  May I ask why?  There are downsides to doing this and if this is a project that may evolve, you'd very possibly be better off using something else.

Comment: This is my first time using Serialization. If there are better ways of Storing and Accessing objects then I am not aware of them. I figured this was a simple issue that I was overlooking. I would look into other options, however I do not have the immediate time to do so.

Comment: Serialization breaks encapsulation, because all the nontransient private fields become part of the exported API of your class as soon as you use the keywords `implements` `Serializable`.  Unless your class is very simple, you'll want to take care to design a serialized form that you can live with for the long haul and which does not leak unnecessary implementation details into the object stream.  The object stream should represent the optimal logical form of your class instance's state rather than it's *actual* state.  You may wish to read about the Serialization Proxy pattern.